# Break out of an infinite loop after specific input, and formatting of saved information

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having an issue with my program where when I enter "q" to break out of the program, I end up in an infinite loop of "Done." I can't figure out why the program isn't breaking and continuing on.

```
filename = input("Enter filename:")
f = open(filename,'w')
print ("File", filename, "created")
firstname = input("Enter first name or Q to quit:")
while firstname == "Q":
    break
print ("Done")
lastname = input("Enter last name:")
zipcode = input("Enter zipcode:")
string = firstname,lastname,zipcode
f.write(str(string)+ '\n')
print ("Data saved")
firstname_second = input("Enter first name or Q to quit:")
while firstname_second == "Q":
    break
print ("Done")
lastname_second = input("Enter last name:")
zipcode_second = input("Enter zipcode:")
string_second = firstname_second,lastname_second,zipcode_second
f.write(str(string_second)+'\n')
print ("Data saved")
firstname_third = input("Enter first name or Q to quit:")
while firstname_third == "Q":
    break
print ("Done")
lastname_third = input("Enter last name:")
zipcode_third = input("Enter zipcode:")
string_third = firstname_third,lastname_third,zipcode_third
f.write(str(string_third))
print ("Data saved")
f.close()
print ("Done")
```

If I chose to not kill the program and instead continue on, I am receiving output like this:
('Firstname', 'Lastname', 'zipcode')
When I am trying to have the output end up like this:
Firstname,Lastname,zipcode

Is there a step I'm missing?
Also, I'm sure there is a way for the program to not look so clunky, but I'm very new to programming so I'm glad I got this far. Thanks for any help/input!

Answer (score 0):

try this

I think it would be better to have one while loop and use if statements to break out of the program depending on the input

```
while(True):
    filename = input("Enter filename:")
    f = open(filename,'w')
    print ("File", filename, "created")
    firstname = input("Enter first name or Q to quit:")
    if firstname == "Q":
        break
    print ("Done")
    lastname = input("Enter last name:")
    zipcode = input("Enter zipcode:")
    string = firstname,lastname,zipcode
    f.write(str(string)+ '\n')
    print ("Data saved")
    firstname_second = input("Enter first name or Q to quit:")
    if firstname_second == "Q":
        break
    print ("Done")
    lastname_second = input("Enter last name:")
    zipcode_second = input("Enter zipcode:")
    string_second = firstname_second,lastname_second,zipcode_second
    f.write(str(string_second)+'\n')
    print ("Data saved")
    firstname_third = input("Enter first name or Q to quit:")
    if firstname_third == "Q":
        break
    print ("Done")
    lastname_third = input("Enter last name:")
    zipcode_third = input("Enter zipcode:")
    string_third = firstname_third,lastname_third,zipcode_third
    f.write(str(string_third))
    print ("Data saved")
    f.close()
    print ("Done")
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my infinite loop problem. Now how do I get it to stop looping through the entire program after all the input? It wants to go right back to "Enter filename"

Comment: If you dont want it to restart you can just put a break statement at the end